# Finding the most frequent String in a sorted ArrayList without using HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, counter

Considering an `ArrayList` of `String`'s containing

```
animalsArray[dog, cat, dog, dog, cat, duck, duck, dog]
```

I could easily use `HashMap`'s to find the most common `String`, using the `HashMap` value as a counter, and the key to store the animal name.

If the `ArrayList` was sorted

```
[dog, dog, dog, dog, cat, cat, duck, duck]
```

What is the easiest way to find the most common element without using `Hashmaps`? I was thinking about using a for loop comparing `animalArray.get(i)` with  `animalArray.get(i-1)` but I wasn't able to develop this solution. And what are the advantages, if there are any, of having a sorted `ArrayList` when we need we need to find the most common element?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the easiest way to find the most common element without using Hashmaps?

I would consider (Java 8+) this to be quite easy:

```
String str = list.stream()
                 .distinct()
                 .max(Comparator.comparing(e -> Collections.frequency(list, e)))
                 .get();
```

Which will create a `Stream` of the `List`, and find the element with the most frequency in the `List`.

> And what are the advantages, if there are any, of having a sorted ArrayList when we need we need to find the most common element?

Imagine an unsorted `List`:

```
[dog, cat, turtle, cat, dog, snake]
```

For every element, you will have to search the rest of the `List` to see how many times it occurs.

However with a sorted `List`:

```
[dog, dog, cat, cat, snake, turtle]
```

You only have to have a counter to keep track of the longest sublist that contains the same elements. Then it turns into something like (psuedocode):

```
//T being the type of the List
T element
int count = 0;
int biggestCount = 0;
for(every element in the list) {
   if the item is the same as previous
      count++
   else 
      //Only check when we're about to change elements
      if count > biggestCount
          biggestCount = count
          element = current element of List
      //Starting over with a new element
      count = 1
}
return element
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! if i got your loop right, at the end of the loop you would return the highest number, which is amazing, but not the name of the animal associated to it. Also, tell me if I am wrong, counting using hashmaps would result in time complexity O(n), while sorting using Collection.sort is O(n log n) + the for loop to find the highest which should be O(n) so in the end O(n log n) + O(n)?

Comment: @jaymartines Yes the loop I showed was just to illustrate that finding the greatest element in the sorted was much easier than an unsorted. And yes using a `HashMap` allows for only one iteration over the loop so it has the better time complexity, assuming the `List` is unsorted.